# open polygons infowindow with click on a html element

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm writing google api 3 code, here: http://jsfiddle.net/zVaGN/2/ 
First i call the two Fusiontables to appear on the map, then i created a html element outside the map which should, when clicked, open a custom infowindow which i have previously created in Fusiontables. So i don't know how to make a function which will call the already created infowindows from the fusiontables when i click on a html element.
So i want this efect http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_egeotestmon.htm
But mine should call the custom infowindows from fusiontables that already exist. How to do this???

Thanks anyone!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the reply Eric. I didn't know this, i tried with a function that would look like this:

```
function izbor() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
query: {" SELECT 'ExtendedData' FROM " + tableid};
    });
infowindow.open(map);
}
```

But i don't know what to call from the table, what is the name of infowindows in the fusiontables.. I called for ExtendedData, because when i exported the fusiontable to kml file, that was the code for the infowindow, but this code for google api 3 that i wrote probably isn't good..

**UPDATE #2**

I have tried it here, but it doesnt work..
jsfiddle.net/zVaGN/4/

Thank You anyway for the help, if You come up with some other solution, please write!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in Fusion Tables. In Fusion Tables you don't really have control over the creation of the overlays displayed on the map, whether markers or polygons.  Fusion Tables is creating tiles on the fly with the overlays already rendered and AFAIK you have no control over the click events on them, besides using infoWindowSuppress: false,  which does allow you to display your own infoWindow with the values returned from the FT click event.

**EDIT**

This function will display the html returned from Fusion Tables. Seems like there should be a way to trigger a click event on the layer from within the page.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e){
     alert(e.infoWindowHtml);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric. I didn't know this, i tried with a function that would look like this: 

function izbor() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
query: {" SELECT 'ExtendedData' FROM " + tableid};
 });
infowindow.open(map);
} 


But I don't know the name of the fusiontables generated infowindow to call for a specific polygon.. Thanks for the answer anyway!